# Is there a single word noun that is equivalent to "night owl" or "someone who regularly stays up too late"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If possible, perhaps with a very mildly negative connotation, with the suggestion that said behavior of staying up late is not necessarily productive and potentially avoidable.

Comment: Metaphorical 'owl' is often used without the adjective, contrasting with 'lark'.

Comment: I don't know a *single* word, but I had a look online to see if the phrase 'dirty stop-up' existed as a variation of 'dirty stop-out' and it apparently  does- to some extent at least. A 'dirty stop-out' is, in British English, someone who stays out later than than is thought proper, though it's use is now generally jocular it is pejorative.

Comment: It seems that 'moonlighter' __used__ to mean "commit crimes at night". That would be very close for you if it still did, but it doesn't anymore. But most of the time, if you're moonlighting, whatever you're doing might be considered a possible interference to your 'day' job. However, it's generally seen as doing some activity, not just sitting around watching late night T.V.

Comment: There's [*lucubrator*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lucubrator), but I'd say its connotations are closer to mildly-positive than mildly-negative, at least in regards to the staying-up-late. Of course, the pejorative term that I've most often heard used by morning people is *lazy*, in reference to when night owls arise in the morning as much as to when they (we) go to bed.

Comment: The M-W Thesaurus gives *nighthawk* as a synonym for *night owl*, but I am unsure if this has the desired connotation.

Comment: In addition to @Scrooble's *nighthawk*, there's also *nightbird*, both defined by [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nightbird) as *another term for night owl*

Comment: nocturnal of course refers to be active at night. "Prone to" carries a slight pejorative meaning of "falling into a behavior" rather than purposefully choosing a behavior" - **nocturnally-prone** might convey the spirit of what you're trying to express

Comment: I might coin the term **sleep dodger** writing a paragraph or article on people tending to be night-owls to prolong non-work hours etc... I can understand the desire to avoid slightly cliche idiom "night owl"

Comment: *Procrastinator*.

Comment: **Night owl** is a "single"  word.

Comment: Are you referring to someone who stays up late and still gets up early (little sleep), or just someone whose body clock is shifted to a later schedule?  Staying up late not being productive could be correct for the first case, but not for the second.

Answer (score 1):

**Night owl** is a "single word." Ignore the space. You could write it nightowl. At any rate  it's a single  *compound word*.

See the post on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/).

Comment: Here's a [link](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/) for you to add to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

***[Insomniac](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/insomniac)*** may be what you are looking for. Although its official (medical) definition is someone who *can't* sleep; in unofficial, informal uses, this word's meaning shades over into someone who *won't* sleep.

Also, since you're trying to imply compulsive, self-destructive behavior, it's perfect for someone whose true insomnia is brought about by their compulsion.

Finally, if you're amenable to a multi-word idiom, English has  one that means precisely what you want : ***burning the candle at both ends***.

([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/burn-the-candle-at-both-ends)):

> to work or do other things from early in the morning until late at night and so get very little rest

Comment: An excuse to quote one of my favourite poems: 'My candle burns at both ends;    It will not last the night; But ah, my foes, and oh, my friends—    It gives a lovely light!'

Comment: @Spagirl Thank you for your poetic reassurance on my intractable nocturnal activites!

Comment: This is close, but the common interpretation of insomniac seems to be more along the lines of "one who has trouble sleeping" vs. "one who chooses not to sleep." Of all the great suggestions offered so far I think "night owl" best captures what I want to communicate, so I'll have to accept that there may not be an appropriate single word in the situation.